# Wix with MVC Areas

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am trying to use Wix on an MVC 3 application with Areas.

```
Contoso.csproj
  /areas
     /Contoso.Widgets.csproj
     /Contoso.Analysis.csproj
```

the files under areas are not included in the Contoso.Ui.csproj, but use project references instead, similar to the Orchard CMS project.

At the moment I can only get the views and files etc that are referenced under the Contoso.Ui.csproj project to be included in the Wix wxs file, how can I get all the other views etc from the other projects to be included?

Comment: What do you mean by include them? Are you running heat on the project and the files aren't being included? If you just need the files to appear in the .wxs file you could manually type them in right?

Comment: If you type it in to the file, then does it not get wiped out next time you compile?

Comment: If you are using heat to dynamically generate the WiX source everytime yes. Is that what you are trying to do? Does your content change frequently to need to dynamically generate the source every build?